# Can food be grown/raised underground in a sustainable way?

Tags: survival, underground, caves

Is it possible to grow plants or raise animals underground, in a way that is enough for 1 person to survive and easy enough to maintain?

Conditions:

- underground;
- without any on-going help from the surface (some initial help to set the system up is acceptable);
- Without sunlight;
- technology level can be described as modern.

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=police+bust+indoor+pot+farm On a related note, my niece bought a house and found evidence of the previous owners' hobby dug into the ground behind a panel in the basement.

Comment: The cave ecosystem is a thing.  Its lifeforms are vibrant and diverse.  Some, like the bats, leave for a few hours a day.  Others, like glow worms and the specialized fish and crustaceans in the cave pools, never do.  if you can make food out of those, you're all set.

Comment: Growing Eatable Algae is another option, a popular one is called Spirulina (http://www.spirulinaacademy.com/grow-your-own-spirulina/). I'm not sure if algae is classed as plant, but it can be cultured in exactly the same way.

Comment: where the energy source?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.
If you have a water supply, which can largely be recycled, and a nutrient supply, which can be recycled (sterilized human waste even) then you don't need much room.

They say it takes 1 acre to feed a person, but with hydroponics you could have multiple levels in a small area, growing more vertically than horizontally, and save a lot of space.

[They are setting up farms in New Jersy night clubs](http://qz.com/705398/the-price-of-leds-is-falling-so-fast-its-profitable-to-farm-in-a-new-jersey-nightclub/) to provide locally grown food to urban environments.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sure you just need electricity and water and something to convert O2 to CO2

You run lamps to replace the sun light and create a farm.  You water it and breath to convert the O2 from the plants to CO2 which they can use.  The farmer needs a supply of fertilizer ( it may be from him to keep the soil rich) or he needs to rotate crops in that replace lost nutrients like soy beans.

Comment: You also need massive cooling of your facility.

Comment: I am not sure I need massive cooling but sure radiate heat into the surrounding ground